# Connection string of DataContext is not modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have data context

```
public class KOATUUContext : DbContext
{
    static KOATUUContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<KOATUUContext>(null);
    }

    public KOATUUContext()
        : base("KOATUU")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<KOATUU> KOATUUs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TerType> TerTypes { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new KOATUUMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RegionMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TerTypeMap());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
}
```

I want my context to load correct connection string so I have specified the following in root web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<connectionStrings>
<add name="RealEstateAgency"
         connectionString="data source=DIMIAS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="KOATUU" connectionString="Data Source=streamer2005\tc;Initial Catalog=KOATUU;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Could you tell me what problem might be? The result of execution - default connection string to SQL Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only used database first and when the DbContext is generated the connection name is not specified like this:

```
    public KOATUUContext()
            : base("KOATUU")
        {
        }
```

but like this:

```
    public KOATUUContext()
            : base("name=KOATUU")
        {
        }
```

Perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: I tried that. Then error is thrown that could not find connection string with such name in application config file.

Comment: I can't see anything else wrong except that you may not have published the changes you made to the web.config correctly; or summing like that

Comment: Thanks, a sit turned out i have posted changes to wrong config file.